# How to resolve `file missing` error when autoloading in Emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, loading, autoload

I'm running into this error when trying to load an auto generated `autoload.el` file using `loaddefs-generate` function. The following is how I did

```lisp
;;; core-autoload.el -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defvar generated-autoload-file nil
  "This is neccessary, otherwise raise error.
`Defining as dynamic an already lexical var`.")

(defvar chidori-autoload-file
  (expand-file-name "autoload.el" chidori-cache-dir)
  "Autoload file.")

(defun chidori-autoload/generate-define (loaddef &rest DIRS)
  "LOADDEF DIRS."
  (let ((generated-autoload-file loaddef))
    (when (or (not (file-exists-p generated-autoload-file))
              noninteractive)
      (loaddefs-generate DIRS chidori-autoload-file))))

(defun chidori-autoload/reload ()
  "Generate autoload file from `core/autoload'."
  (interactive)
  (when (file-exists-p chidori-autoload-file)
    (delete-file chidori-autoload-file t)
    (message "delete old autoload file: %s" chidori-autoload-file))

  (chidori-autoload/generate-define chidori-autoload-file chidori-autoload-dir)
  (load chidori-autoload-file nil 'nomessage)
  (message "generate autoload file: %s done." chidori-autoload-file))

(unless (file-exists-p chidori-autoload-file)
  (chidori-autoload/reload))

(load chidori-autoload-file nil 'nomessage)

(provide 'core-autoload)
;; core-autoload.el ends here
```

And this is part of generated autoload file

```lisp
;;; autoload.el --- automatically extracted autoloads (do not edit)   -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
;; Generated by the `loaddefs-generate' function.

;; This file is part of GNU Emacs.

;;; Code:
;;; Generated autoloads from ../../autoload/package.el

(autoload 'package! "../../autoload/package")

;;; and many other autoloads
```

However, when I start Emacs, the error occurred saying it `(file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "../../autoload/package"`

If I manually edit to absolute path, the issue is gone. But I don't think it's right way to do.

Can anyone help me out?

My draft for further reference:

[https://git.sr.ht/~bangedorrunt/chidori-emacs](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebangedorrunt/chidori-emacs)

The following is my system information:

```
OS: macOS 12.6
Emacs versions: emacs-plus@29
Terminal: Wezterm
Shell: fish
```

Comment: You haven't shown a declaration for `chidori-autoload-dir` (which gets passed to `loaddefs-generate`).  What is that?

Comment: @phils it's `(defconst chidori-autoload-dir (expand-file-name "autoload/" user-emacs-directory))`
I have absolutely have no idea why it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue.

In my config, I got

```lisp
(defvar chidori-etc-dir (expand-file-name "etc/" user-emacs-directory))
(defvar chidori-cache-dir (expand-file-name "cache/" chidori-etc-dir))
```

The issue is fixed if I replace `chidori-etc-dir` with the following

```lisp
(defvar chidori-cache-dir (expand-file-name "cache/" user-emacs-directory))
```

From my understanding, we couldn't 2 level nested dir for autoload file. This also happen if I write autoload file to `user-emacs-directory`.